# Entity Framework - Single Entity to Multiple Tables

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am having some difficulty in mapping single entity to a two different tables in a Entity Framework out of which one is optional to give a quick overview.

I have one main table which is of a core table that lot of our applications in our company uses it, so we really don't want to make any changes to this table.

In our new application we needed a few more columns to support some of the features we are adding.

I have created a single Entity Model that will save information to both these tables, it is working fine when both these tables has the records (related by primary key and foreign key)

But for the historical record this new table will not have a associated record and not able to fetch any entity set.

Below is the code snippet.

```
public class ModelTable
{
    public string PatientID { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis1 { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis2 { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis3 { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis4 { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis5 { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis6 { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis7 { get; set; }

    public string Diagnosis8 { get; set; }
}

public class ModelTableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ModelTable>
{
    public ModelTableMap()
    {
        //Table1
        this.Map(model =>
        {
            model.Properties(table1 => new
            {
                table1.Diagnosis1,
                table1.Diagnosis2,
                table1.Diagnosis3,
                table1.Diagnosis4,
                table1.Diagnosis5,
                table1.Diagnosis6
            });
            model.ToTable("Table1");
        });
        //Optional Table
        this.Map(model =>
        {
            model.Properties(table2 => new
            {
                table2.Diagnosis7,
                table2.Diagnosis8,
            });
            model.ToTable("Table2");
        });

        this.HasKey(type => type.PatientID);
        this.Property(type => type.PatientID).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag1");
        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag2");
        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag3");
        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag4");
        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag5");
        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag6");
        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag7");
        this.Property(type => type.Diagnosis1).HasColumnName("Diag8");
    }

}
```

If I split these tables into a two different POCO classes and specify the relationshipt it is working fine.

But I want to achieve this with Single Entity, since functionally it is a same table.

Please provide any guidance or if I am doing any wrong and please bare with my English is not that good.

Thanks
Sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity splitting in current EF version requires records in both tables. If you want to use entity splitting you must create empty record for all existing records from the first table. Otherwise you cannot use entity splitting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I guess in this case I have to live with two separate entities and have them related.